# Can't delete any files in my download folder

Tags: cyanogenmod, profiles, file-permissions

asus sl101 slider running cyanogenmod 10

This problem actually started around when I upgraded to cm9.1 and I think I got an error that my android profile had changed or something. from that day forward I have been unable to delete anything in my downloads folder.

The following did not work

- rm /sdcard/download/filename
- removing with rootbrowser
- adb shell> rm /sdcard/download/filename
- remounting the sdcard

---

I get the error that the folder is read only and when I try to change permissions it wont let me.

I was able to

mv /sdcard/download /sdcard/download.back
mkdir /sdcard/download

but still cannot delete from the old download folder.

Eek!

Comment: can you paste here the output of `ls -ld /sdcard/download; mount | grep sdcard` ?

Comment: u0_a37@android:/ # ls -ld /sdcard/download; mount | grep sdcard
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2012-09-30 00:27 download
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0

Comment: is it possible that a program like titanium backup is somehow rotecting them even above root?

Comment: Did you try the full real path ? `rm -rf /mnt/sdcard/download`

Comment: I just tried it now and got the error, "read-only file system" the trouble is, it's not true. other things on sdcard delete fine.

Comment: What is the output of `df /mnt/sdcard/download` ?

Comment: I think the only fix would be to somehow reformat the sdcard and somehow nvflash a rom, but the sbkey is not available for my device. it is rootable but not nvflashable. I can boot ubuntu on it but for some reason inside of ubuntu im not able to mount the sdcard

Comment: Any reply to my question ? =)

Comment: 255|u0_a37@android:/ $ df mnt/sdcard/download  
Filesystem             Size   Used   Free   Blksize  
mnt/sdcard/download     26G    25G   762M   2048  
u0_a37@android:/ $

Comment: Just an update but I'd never found a solution to this problem. Ended up wiping the system and starting from scratch. Problem files , gone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're still having this issue or not, but a couple of things that come to mind:

- In the output you paste in your responses, you mix terminal output with `$` and `#`. You need to be root *all the time* which means that you should always see a `#`.
- If I were you, I would first check the permissions on the old download directory with something like `ls -alh | grep <foldername>`. Who owns the directory, what group?
- Try changing ownership with `chown`, changing chmod to `777` recursively (just throwing stuff at the wall here to see what sticks). After setting yourself (root) as the owner and giving everyone full rights to the directory *recursively*, I would try `rm -rfv <foldername>` and see what output I got.

Hopefully this might help someone else. Also, when you do `ls -alh` it should show you if it's a symlink, and if so to where. If it's a mounted folder, I would run something like `mount | grep <foldername>` to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. The -h flag does not work in the android terminal. All the files already belong to root user and group seems to be 'sdcard_rw' . chmod 777 * returns no errors but does not change anything at all. Permissions remain rwxrwxr-x

Answer (score 0):

You have a special mount point* for `/mnt/sdcard/download`, so

- umount it with `umount /mnt/sdcard/download`
- remove the directory `rm -rf /mnt/sdcard/download`

And try to figure out what cause your Android to use this special mount.

If you just want read-write access, run this command : `mount -o remount,rw /mnt/sdcard/download` and then you will be able to `rm` anything inside.

*figured out by the discussions in your question thread

Comment: u0_a37@android:/ $ umount /mnt/sdcard/download
failed: Invalid argument

Comment: 1|u0_a37@android:/ # mount -o remount,rw /mnt/sdcard/download
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory
1|u0_a37@android:/ #

Comment: i wonder if some parental software i installed a long while back or titanium backup or some software is causing this. but i deleted all the data and cache before flashing this rom. several times...

Comment: You should be root to do it

Comment: sorry, copy pasted the wrong line.     ----------------------- 
u0_a37@android:/ # umount /mnt/sdcard/download
failed: Invalid argument

Comment: Strange, no idea.

Comment: thanks for all your help sputnick. If I ever find the answer I'll pass it your way. I've had nothing but trouble with this device since day one and will never recommend it to anyone ever again. I wish I'd gone with the tf101.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `/sdcard` is just a link. You may need to make your changes in the actual location of the data at `/data/media`. An answer to a similar question was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981687/cant-delete-directory-form-storage-sdcard0/21815450#21815450).